# Check if adobe reader is installed on client machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, adobe-reader

Currently I am working on a web page which will tell user about certain configurations on client machine. Out of this there is also requirement of detecting if Adobe Reader is installed on client machine or not. I am using ASP.NET/C#.

I have looked the following url for the answer
"[Check Adobe Reader is installed (C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969027/check-adobe-reader-is-installed-c)" but the code look into the server registry entires where IIS is installed and not the client machine where browser is running.

Is it possible to detect if Adobe reader is installed on client machine and not the server which is hosting the website?

Answer (score 3):

pls, check the script below, it worked fine for me in IE, FireFox and Chrome

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var found = false;
var info = '';

try 
{    
    acrobat4 = new ActiveXObject('PDF.PdfCtrl.1');    
    if (acrobat4) 
    {      
        found = true;      
        info = 'v. 4.0';    
    }  
}  
catch (e) 
{
    //???
}

if (!found)
{
    try 
    {
        acrobat7 = new ActiveXObject('AcroPDF.PDF.1');
        if (acrobat7) 
        {
            found = true;
            info = 'v. 7+';
        }
    } 
    catch (e) 
    {
        //???
    }

    if (!found && navigator.plugins && navigator.plugins.length>0)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i<navigator.plugins.length; i++) 
        {                           
            if (navigator.plugins[i].name.indexOf('Adobe Acrobat') > -1)
            {
                found = true; 
                info = navigator.plugins[i].description + ' (' + navigator.plugins[i].filename + ')';
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

document.write("Acrobat Reader Installed : " + found);
document.write("<br />");
if (found) document.write("Info : " + info);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Is there a way to check in asp.net code if the installed adobe reader is up to date, or if there is a new update available?

Answer (score 1):

I used this script and called it on ready function :
Note: i used the alerts here just to know how to use it.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         alert(getAcrobatInfo().browser);
         alert(getAcrobatInfo().acrobat === "installed");
         alert(getAcrobatInfo().acrobatVersion);
     });


     var getAcrobatInfo = function () {

         var getBrowserName = function () {
             return '<%=Session["browser"].ToString()%>';
         };

         var getActiveXObject = function (name) {
             try { return new ActiveXObject(name); } catch (e) { }
         };

         var getNavigatorPlugin = function (name) {
             for (key in navigator.plugins) {
                 var plugin = navigator.plugins[key];
                 if (plugin.name == name) return plugin;
             }
         };

         var getPDFPlugin = function () {
             return this.plugin = this.plugin || function () {
                 if (getBrowserName() == 'ie' || getBrowserName().toLocaleLowerCase() == 'internetexplorer') {
                     //
                     // load the activeX control
                     // AcroPDF.PDF is used by version 7 and later
                     // PDF.PdfCtrl is used by version 6 and earlier
                     return getActiveXObject('AcroPDF.PDF') || getActiveXObject('PDF.PdfCtrl');
                 }
                 else {
                     return  getNavigatorPlugin('Adobe Acrobat') || getNavigatorPlugin('Chrome PDF Viewer') || getNavigatorPlugin('WebKit built-in PDF') || getWebKitPlugin();
                 }
             }();
         };
         var getWebKitPlugin = function () {
             for (var key in navigator.plugins) {
                 var plugin = navigator.plugins[key];
                 if (plugin.name && plugin.name.substring(0, 6) == "WebKit" && (plugin.name.indexOf("pdf") != -1 || plugin.name.indexOf("PDF") != -1)) return plugin;
             }
         };
         var isAcrobatInstalled = function () {
             return !!getPDFPlugin();
         };
         var getAcrobatVersion = function () {
             try {
                 var plugin = getPDFPlugin();

                 if (getBrowserName() == 'ie' || getBrowserName().toLocaleLowerCase() == 'internetexplorer') {
                     var versions = plugin.GetVersions().split(',');
                     var latest = versions[0].split('=');
                     return parseFloat(latest[1]);

                 }
                 if (plugin.version) return parseInt(plugin.version);
                 return plugin.name


             }
             catch (e) {
                 return null;
             }
         }

         // The returned object
         return {
             browser: getBrowserName(),
             acrobat: isAcrobatInstalled() ? 'installed' : false,
             acrobatVersion: getAcrobatVersion()
         };
     };
</script>
```

Also add this code behind:

```
  public void detectBrowser()
     { //Set the Browser session variable
       System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = Request.Browser;
       Session["Browser"] = browser.Browser;
    }
```

Hope it helps.