# c#: Check if a control is there

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, controls

I'm using in vc# 2k8 a control that is not standard! If someone starts my program without having the program, that my control is for, he'll get an exception!

How to check if you can use this control or don't...

The program should also work without that control and without the features that uses it by a condition!

EDIT: I'm sorry, I meant I have a AcrobatReader control but my program crashes if you don't have the Reader installed

Comment: "If someone starts my program without having the program"

Comment: Shouldn't you be distributing this control with your program? Is your question on how to distribute it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are wanting to check to to see if Adobe Reader is installed, then this is a duplicate question to this one:

[Check if adobe reader is installed on client machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715299/check-if-adobe-reader-is-installed-on-client-machine)

EDIT: Just realized that the previous answer was for within IE. This link should be for C#

[Check Adobe Reader is installed (C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969027/check-adobe-reader-is-installed-c)