# C# 4.0: System.Diagnostics.Process

Tags: c#, file, c#-4.0, system.diagnostics

Hi I would like to know if there's an existing implementation of checking if **application(Acrobat Reader)** exist in your local machine before I start to open it.

for example I want to open a pdf file and i dont have an acrobat reader, so **how will I  check If I have an installed program for me to open the file?**.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("path.pdf")
```

Comment: Do you want to know if a specific application exists, e.g. "Acrobat Reader"? Or do you want to know whether there is an (unspecified) application associated with a given file type, e.g. "is there something (Acrobat Reader, Acrobat, Foxit, ...) that can open PDFs available?"

Comment: I want to know if a specific application exists in my local machine. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look at [Windows: List and Launch applications associated with an extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954/windows-list-and-launch-applications-associated-with-an-extension) and IQueryAssociations.

Answer (score 2):

Programmatically, here is how you'd [check if Acrobat Reader is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969027/check-adobe-reader-is-installed-c).

Also you may check manually, if you have acrobat reader installed; somewhere here  `YourInstallationDrive:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 8.0\Reader`.

And then you may open the PDF like following:

```
Process.Start("AcroRd32.exe", "c:\myfile.pdf");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check this registery key to get the installed applications
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

See the following [article](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1995.htm)

Answer (score 0):

use `System.IO.File.Exists("Your Path")`

Comment: This is not what he's asking, he wants to know if there is a default program associated with the file extension.